# SQL Server retain user access after Restore

Tags: sql-server

I am working in an environment which has multiple sql server instances.
  In one server my user is able to access any database even after restore.
  In another server my user losses access to the database after doing a restore.
  What could be the difference in access for my user in both servers.

Comment: This may help: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1590/understanding-and-dealing-with-orphaned-users-in-a-sql-server-database/

Answer (score 1):

probably in your first instance, your user has `sysadmin` privileges. on the other hand in second SQL instance, your user have database level privileges which are overridden upon restore.